# Javascript - Edit the content of a tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page with a header that has a height determined by the content in it, as well as margins. While I scroll down the page, javascript removes the margin, resulting in a header that is only about 50px in height. And then it sticks to the top.

Now, I'm using gumby and gumby has a built-in `gumby-goto` that skips to a specified ID.
And I'm using this in the header links. So when the page is all the way at the top, `gumby-goto` skips to the location, but meanwhile, it doesn't know about the javascript that has resized the header. So I end up in the location *minus* the difference in height of the header.

The HTML code is as simple as this..

```
<li><a class="skip" href="#" gumby-goto="#studio">STUDIO</a></li>
```

I figured I could use javascript to get the hight of the header, and then append that into the HTML tag. So I should alter the code to this:

```
<li><a class="skip" href="#" gumby-goto="#studio" gumby-offset="-80">STUDIO</a></li>
```

Where the `gumby-offset="-80"` is the calculated edit. 
But is it possible to append data to an element? Do I have to extract the whole contents of the tag, and then break it up into two string, stitch the parameter in, and then stitch the whole string back together?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('.skip').attr('gumby-offset', -80);
```

Comment: Oh my God, about the only thing I didn't try already.. I knew it had to be that simple! Lots of thanx!

Comment: Although this code works correctly, it seems as though gumby only takes the parameter on page load.

Comment: @KennyBones can you not initialize gumby again after this code? (or at least only for specific divs)